# Android Retrofit response returning null object

Tags: android, django, retrofit

I had built a simple rest API using `Django` on my localhost and was trying to access the `GET`, `POST` methods using android `retrofit`. I have successfully used the `GET` method & retrieved the JSON objects in a simple android `TextView`. But when I tried using `POST` from the remote android device, it did return with code 500(which is called internal server error). But my `POST` is working from the localhost server. I can't figure out why the POST is not working and so the `response.body()` is returning a null object to my `Post` class.
Here is my `createPost()` which I tried to Post something on the localhost Django Server:

```
private void createPost() {
        Post post = new Post("AAAAAAAA", "33");
        Call<Post> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.createPost(post);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                    tv.setText("Code" + response.code());
                }

                Post postResponse = response.body();
                String content = "";
                content += postResponse.getAlias() + "\n";
                content += postResponse.getName() + "\n\n";

                tv.append(content);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
                tv.setText(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

And my Post class:

```
public class Post {
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("alias")
    private String alias;

    public Post(String name, String alias) {
        this.name = name;
        this.alias = alias;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }
}
```

And in my JsonPlaceHolderApi Interface:

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {
    @GET("heroes")
    Call<List<Post>> getPosts();


    @POST("heroes")
    Call<Post> createPost(@Body Post post);
}
```

Finally, in my logcat window, I got:

```
2020-07-02 21:47:31.858 25271-25271/com.asif.restapitestapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.asif.restapitestapp, PID: 25271
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.asif.restapitestapp.Post.getAlias()' on a null object reference
        at com.asif.restapitestapp.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:79)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6517)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post logs ?

Comment: Can you try web service in postman ?

Comment: @MD are you suggesting to test my RESTful API with postman?

Comment: Yes if you're getting 500 error then might be server side issue that why for cross checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an extra slash "/" to the `@POST` solved my issue.

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {
    @GET("heroes")
    Call<List<Post>> getPosts();


    @POST("heroes/")
    Call<Post> createPost(@Body Post post);
}
```